# Function mutating union type array pushes incorrect value type into array

Tags: typescript

I've observed this non-typesafe behavior, which I simply cannot wrap my head around:

```
type StrNum = string | number;
const strArr: string[] = [];
function addToArray(arr: StrNum[]): void {
  arr.push(1);
}
addToArray(strArr);
console.log(strArr[0]); // 1
console.log(typeof strArr[0]); // "number"
```

How is it that this compiles without error? Can such occurrences be detected? This seems as though is should not be permissible to begin with, yet the above code compiles without error or warning.

I have executed the above code and observed the results described. I am simply seeking additional information on the matter.

Comment: why do you think it should be an issue or the code that you provided should throw error?

Comment: @user-id-14900042 Indeed it does! Thank-you!